# Generate All Paths With a Given Start and End Point

Tags: python, loops, graph, iteration

This seemed like a simple problem, but actually implementing it into code is giving me a lot of trouble. I'm looking to write a loop in Python that iterates through all possible distinct paths of length `L`.

The first node in this path must be 0, and the last node must be the integer `n - 1`. Every node in between the first and last nodes can be any integer in `[0 , n-1]` but must be distinct from the one node preceding it and the one node succeeding it.

`n` can be any integer in `[2, 7]`, and `L` can be any integer >= 3.

For example, if `n = 4` and `L = 3`, the loop should iterate through

```
[ 0, 1, 3]
[ 0, 2, 3]
```

For `n = 4`, and `L = 4` the loop should iterate through

```
[ 0, 1, 0, 3]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3]
[ 0, 2, 0, 3]
[ 0, 2, 1, 3]
[ 0, 3, 0, 3]
[ 0, 3, 1, 3]
[ 0, 3, 2, 3]
```

The process I was thinking of to generate this path is as follow.

1. iterate through all numbers 0 to `( n - 1)^(L-3)`.
2. convert those numbers to base `n - 1`
3. convert that back to a string, append 0s to the left until it is of length `L - 3`.
4. for each of these numbers, iterate through all digits `[0, n-2]` and append those digits to the right. Call these our `path_ids`
5. Start a new path with first node [0]
6. For each digit in the `path_id`, but the last create a list `x = range(n)`, remove the previous node in the path from `x`, and append `x[ digit]` to your path
7. For the last digit in your path id create `x = range(n)` remove the last node in your path and `n-1` from `x`, append `x[ digit]` to your path.
8. Append `n-1` to the end of the path.

This seems like a very complex process for my problem and may end up slowing my code down to a point that it's unusable. I'm looking for a simple way to do this. This process will be within an iteration of all possible path lengths, and I will iterate over each path generated and check that it meets certain conditions, and if so, I'll store it. I will then iterate through every path that meets those conditions and check some other condition for the best ones. There will likely be many 'best'  paths, so I'll then have to sort them. As you can imagine, writing this one function inefficiently will slow my entire program down immensely.

I apologize for butchering the formatting, I've been lurking for a while, but this is the first question I've asked myself.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: `but actually implementing it into code is giving me a lot of trouble` what have you tried and what trouble are you facing? This is too broad, no one is going to hand you code.

Comment: @greenkraken Can you edit your code/strategy into your question instead of putting it in the comments, so it's easier to help?

Comment: @potential close voters the OP is asking about the correct algorithm to do this. This is far from "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

You want `itertools.product(range(n-1), repeat=L-2)`.  Then compute the cumulative sum of each combination module *n* (starting from 1).  This avoids all duplicates except at the end, which you just check afterward.

(I saw this suggested when a questioner wanted non-repeating random numbers, but it works here as well.  I'll post a link if I can find it again.)